# How to call method inside a select with runat="server"

Tags: asp.net

I have a `select` html element which is populated with the result of a query. The markup is the following:

```
<select runat="server" name="nation" id="nation" class="pure-u-1" data-rule-required="true">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <%= CountryOptions %>
</select>
```

`CountryOptions` is a `String` that returns a list of options for the select element. It was all working fine until I've added the `runat="server"` because I needed to access the select element from the code behind, now the `CountryOptions` does not get initialized and the select is empty.. What is wrong with the code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to fill in your select with a string?

Comment: asp.net, maybe you should use asp:DropDownList

Comment: Why set runat property select element? Can you try to  runat tag remove.

Comment: @NiZa the string contains N option that I fill with the value from the DB Query, it returns a string with all the options that can be assigned to the select. It works fine without the runat="server"

Comment: @Signo, you cannot convert your string to options in your codebehind?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the normal HTML element , maybe look at the asp:DropDownList.

```
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataSourceID="SomeDS" AppendDataBoundItems="true"> // Notice the last property
        <asp:ListItem Text="Please select an option" Value="" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```